# Find equivalent of a destroyed IC (voltage regulator?) - top marking 3P=4G 50Q

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, identification, repair

I’m trying to replace a damaged IC due to accidentally short circuit. But it seems like it’s impossible to find original one. How could I find an alternative?

[image: Picture]

What is 3P=4G 50Q?

---

Photo showing more of the PCB:

[image: Photo showing more of the PCB]

Comment: Why do you think this is a MOSFET?

Comment: Actually I don’t know, but looks similar?

Comment: It doesn't look like a MOSFET at all to me. The capacitors and resistor adjacent to it make it look like some kind of integrated circuit, possibly a voltage regulator.

Comment: This circuit appears on this board multiple times: three capacitance, one resistor with a 3P=4G 50Q. How could I know the probable pinout of it?

Comment: What is the board? Judging by those designators it's quite a complicated circuit. I would trace out what connects to where, and on one of the working ones, what voltages are on each pin relative to ground. I would guess it's a linear regulator, with its input and output capacitors and a feedback resistor, but I'm not certain.

Comment: A 5G baseband processing board from ZTE...

Comment: The chip below is certainly a MOSFET, it’s Infineon’s. https://i.imgur.com/fnk90Vk_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium

Comment: *The chip below is certainly a MOSFET, it’s Infineon’s* Repeating that "it's a MOSFET" doesn't make you any friends here unless you show us **PROOF**, like you measured the pins and found that many of them are shorted resulting in the device having only **three** electrically separate pins and finding a **diode** between some of those pins. Also, what makes you conclude that the device is broken. If you cannot (with proof) say what the device is and have no datasheet then you can only **GUESS**.

Comment: The chip below (440n10n) is Infineon’s BSZ440N10NS3, datasheet here: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BSZ440N10NS3%20G-DS-v02_01-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a304320896aa20120c32dbf312354

Comment: I agree with the others - Based on the stuff around it, I'm also in the "Not a MOSFET" camp.   Voltage regulator makes the most sense, but that's just a guess.   Honestly, your best bet is recycle this unit and buy a new one.  Just because you found a MOSFET with the similar package doesn't mean anything.  There could be anything inside the package -- Opamp, regulator, CPU, SPI EEPROM, etc....   If this were an Infineon device, we should expect an infineon logo on the top, but there's no logo.  The 'chip below' has the infineon logo, and the printing is a different font.

Comment: “the chip below” is not the 3P=4G, it’s the Infineon 440N10N below the 3P=4G...

Comment: its component id is D1A31A2 .... it could be a diode array of some kind ... how are other ICs identified?

Comment: Heting , are pins 5 & 7 across the capacitor?  Could it be a buck or boost regulator with internal Inductor >1MHz

Comment: Yes, pin 5 & 7 are across the capacitor...

Comment: It seems that Richtek uses this kind of marking. 3P= as product code, and the rest as date code. Richtek RT8175A uses 3P= as product code, but the pin count doesn't match.

Comment: I think it’s very possible to be Richtek’s...

Comment: Probably it’s RT2518, also 4 pin and start with 3P. https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT2518/DS2518-05.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Linkyyy

It’s probably Richtek’s RT2518 (linear regulator). Datasheet here: https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT2518/DS2518-05.pdf

Comment: That could definitely be that IC.